# Forge request fails on postman and curl

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

Hello i'm trying the introduction to the design automation ofr inventor but i'm stuck on the upload parameters.

this is the article:

```
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/simple-introduction-design-automation-inventor
```

my last curl request:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com \
  -H 'content-type: application/octet-stream' \
  -F key=apps/Hf3jB7SzAGmZnHhBdRFvVHJEaCa7xPzN/ThumbnailBundle/1 \
  -F policy=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 \
  -F content-type=application/octet-stream \
  -F success_action_status=200 \
  -F success_action_redirect= \
  -F x-amz-signature=2583b27e19fdb5ff23950d6866dc3765c1f1bcd9c9b43d2fb2cbeb252e9e6507 \
  -F x-amz-credential=ASIATGVJZKM3AKEZODGH/20190212/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request/ \
  -F x-amz-algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 \
  -F x-amz-date=20190212T160432Z \
  -F x-amz-server-side-encryption=AES256 \
  -F x-amz-security-token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEGkaDE/d7VjcOZAe6QpkuSLvAVyLORBZv+YHxFPfTf/9LuA2t86VXbXXxhCWd1e83lcUJxfHd8n3dFissoutjHXniplpqnkGivmwE+L56BLCRBp4sbpWVEU5QYpD42A5T/56X/sfyQNVG1p2V9T0i16jY/rmZVgaKyu6kBhognDibkGqoa/+qCbfFrISTEI4gX9kML/0KlYLVtzwlm3t0ZLfUzZ+upyA0hAhHwiYdpy4MadLE47n9B/uTzO1J4qWbcWKis+nC/O/zJXnNuagbgWqh+Snf2Q3hrhiVA42IUqdm1fkh1XlttB8Fk057vyTiQlOQccmss8xpE+mCGGAD0TXKKnVi+MF \
  -F file=@/C:\Users\sejjilali\Desktop\InventorForgeAddInServer.zip
```

[image: Curlresult]

[image: Postman result]

Comment: `@/C:\Users\sejjilali\Desktop\InventorForgeAddInServer.zip`
You don't  need slash before your file path, the blog post is referring a file in an unix style. Try removing slash after @

Comment: still the same result

Comment: it's my fault i found if the path is wiritten ike this **file=@/c/Users/sejjilali/Desktop/InventorThumbnailAddin.zip**

Comment: Okay, you need to use `content-type: multipart/form-data'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your postman request, it look like you have a space at the end of your x-amz-algorithm form-data value.  Try removing it after "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256".

Answer (score 1):

You are using Policy to specify an authorization token, the token needs to be a Header both in your Postman and cURL command "-H 'Authorization: Bearer [token]".

Comment: There's another problem. The fact is my company has a proxy how make many requests fail. is better when my computer is connected to my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Use -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' instead of the octet-stream.

Comment: When you hit orange link "code" in postman on the right, then you can see it in curl syntax.